# Как синхронизировать несколько CRM?

Tags: python, crm

Не могу придумать решение проблемы

Фирма пользуется несколькими CRM:

- amoCRM
- Flowlu

**Как возможно сделать их синхронизацию? Чтобы при добавлении или изменении данных в одной CRM, также менялись или добавлялись эти данные в другой CRM.**
Пишу на Python

Пока представляется только такой вариант:
Создана база данных и программа постоянно получает по API данные из одной CRM и другой CRM.
При изменении в одной из них, вносит их в другую.

Если заказывать на фрилансе написание такой системы, какая ориентировочная цена может быть за нее?